# Python 3 Pandas multiple dataframe columns comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several large datasets containing expected shortfall (a measure of risk) on a large portfolio of exchange-traded products.  I am looking to compare a list of names that I have filtered using specific criteria in Bloomberg to see if there are matches within my first dataset.  I started by exporting the tickers from Bloomberg into a csv file. I also exported my risk information (which has a column of tickers) as a csv file.  I read both of these files into pandas dataframe objects and have isolated the columns I would like to compare.  My risk dataset contains approximately 152,000 entries and my Bloomberg ticker file has 321 names.  Ultimately, I just want to create a new column whereby I indicate whether the entry in my risk dataset is contained in the list of Bloomberg Tickers (ie entries for TRUE/FALSE or 0/1).

[image: Risk Dataframe]

I have tried the following code I found from Stackoverflow

```
china_names['EQY_FUND_CRNCY'].isin(data['Risk Group Symbol']).value_counts()
```

which returns false for every entry, even though I can visually see some matches between the 2

[image: Bloomberg Ticker Dataframe]

I've also tried this :

```py
values = set(data['Risk Group Symbol'])
data['In China?'] = china_names['EQY_FUND_CRNCY'].isin(values)
data['In China?'].describe()
```

It seems that no matter which method I try and compare the columns, I can't identify matches between the two.   I don't understand what I could be doing wrong.  Could the issue be a textual difference between the tickers in `data['Risk Group Symbol']` and `china_names['EQY_FUND_CRNCY']`?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
china_names.loc[china_names['EQY_FUND_CRNCY'].isin(data['Risk Group Symbol'])]['EQY_FUND_CRNCY'].value_counts()
```

Comment: What's the point of using `.loc[]` if you're still going to select the column outside of it?